# I am trying to array index a 4 dimensional numpy array.

Tags: numpy, indexing

i have a 4 dimensional array -- say a=numpy.array(40,40,4,1000)
I also have an index array -- say b = np.arrange(35)
I am looking to make an array doing something like c = a[b,b,3,999] where the resulting array would look something like d = numpy.array(35,35). Would appreciate any thoughts on what the right way to do this is. Thank you. Neela.

Answer (score 0):

Since `b=np.arange(35)` is just the first 35 indices, use slices instead:

```
c = a[:35,:35,3,999]
```

If the values in `b` are not contiguous, then you will need to adjust its shape

```
c = a[b[:,None], b[None,:], 3, 999]
```

e.g.

```
In [754]: a=np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5)
In [755]: b=np.array([2,0,1])
In [756]: a[b[:,None],b[None,:],3]
Out[756]: 
array([[53, 43, 48],
       [13,  3,  8],
       [33, 23, 28]])
```

`b[:,None]` is a `(3,1)` array, `b[None,:]` a `(1,3)`, together they broadcast to `(3,3)` arrays.

You may need to read up on broadcasting and advanced indexing.

More explicitly this indexing is:

```
a[[[2],[0],[1]], [[2,0,1]], 3]
```

`np.ix_` is a handy tool for generating indexes like this:

```
In [795]: I,J = np.ix_(b,b)
In [796]: I
Out[796]: 
array([[2],
       [0],
       [1]])
In [797]: J
Out[797]: array([[2, 0, 1]])
In [798]: a[I,J,3]
Out[798]: 
array([[53, 43, 48],
       [13,  3,  8],
       [33, 23, 28]])
```

Comment: I gave b as an arrange just to indicate it is of size 35. It could be constructed using more complicated rules -- such as a non zero condition on some other array. So what does the None do in the above example? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it.